# Accessing global array more efficient than passing as argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, optimization, stack

I have a function which is called many times and I need to pass an array of 4 or 5 elements down in to 3 or 4 nested functions.

Surely it would be more efficient to create this array data structure as a global variable where all functions can access it with one address reference, rather than passing it down the nested functions as an argument. The latter would require stack pushing and popping whereas the global variable wouldn't?

(I know I can profile, but I want to understand what the theory would suggest- the difference in what code would be executed)

Comment: No, definitely not. If it's a normal array, you're passing a pointer. If it's a `std::array`, pass by reference. If the stack is blowing up from the parameter passing, I think there's a worse problem.

Comment: The stack isn't blowing up- i just thought that a global variable is cheaper to reference than a function argument which needs to be pushed/popped.

Comment: Passing 4 or 5 scalars as separate parameters might even be faster than either. Yeah, you need 3 more registers, but the ABI reserves several registers (probably 4 or more) for parameter passing and you'll have the values *already available*, rather than needing to load them from somewhere. And regarding pushing and popping around calls: A couple registers are very cheap to push and pop, I can't imagine a variant of the global array approach that would improve on it. They all either need the exact same push/pop dance, or do the same thing on non-stack memory.

Comment: @delnan what about the needless POP and PUSH instructions? Thats why I thought passing arguments would be slower (admittedly just!).

Comment: @user997112 Any variant involving a array will have to load from the array, and perhaps keep the loaded value in a register when it's needed again soon. If the caller makes use of the values after the call, then it either needs to PUSH+POP those cached values, or load them again from the array which is at best as expensive as the POP part, possibly slower.

Answer (score 1):

1-first of all an array in C/C++ is just a contiguous area reserved in memory , with a pointer to the first element namely : Arr[0]

2-passing array as a parameter most likely consumes a register in parameter passing (according to calling convention used and count of function parameters)
while using a global variable will not consume this register

3-to the compiler passing the parameter like

```
a) Foo(int* Arr)
b) Foo(int Arr[])
```

is just the same, a pointer is copied to the register or the stack according to calling convention used

the format in (b) may just give a hint to the compiler that there are no overlapping while processing the array to make better optimization

Comment: what about the needless POP and PUSH instructions?

Comment: there are some cost should be paid any way , but register space is a precious resource for the compiler to use during optimization

Comment: any way the passing parameters way either on the stack or within a CPU register is up to the compiler , and the calling convention
which is not the question, the question is passing as a parameter or use a global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer or reference instead of passing whole array.
If it is C plus plus, make that array member variable.

Comment: -1, does not answer the question. The OP asked for the difference in efficiency and was very clear that it is the theory he is interested in. Also, nowhere did the OP say he is using classes.